# number of elements in a span

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I understand the solution to this particular question.
However, this example has raised a general concern.

I was asked to find the minimal number of elements that span the entire vector subspace.
In the example it's proven that one of the 3 vector found initialy to span the subspace is a linear combination of the others and therefore the minimal number of elements to span this subspace of 3 dimentional vectors is eventually 2.

Is the minimal number of elements to span an entire subspace can be lower than the size of the dimention of the space. Meaning, a subspace of a 4 degree polynom can be spanned by less than 4 elements or in the given example 2 vectors of 3 tuples can span a subspace of 3 tupled vectors. I was under the impression that there is a correlation between the two. Feels "wrong". I seem to be lacking something. Is there a rule concerning this matter?

Example of the solution

[image]

Comment: A plane in the 3D space can be spanned by 2 direction vectors, of course. A proper subspace of a finite dimensional vector space always has less dimension. (Recall that the dimension of a vector space is defined to be the smallest number of vectors that can span the space.)

Comment: The dimension of a vector space (and thus of subspaces as well) is defined to be the number of elements in any linearly independent spanning set (equivalently, in any maximal linearly independent set) (equivalently, in any minimal spanning set). For finite-dimensional vector spaces, it's a theorem that all these are equivalent and unambiguous. In particular, it's a theorem that every spanning set has at least as many elements as the dimension of the space.